# can not creating new collection on apache solr

Tags: apache, collections, solr, solr4

I'm try make new collection at Apache solr 4 greater using API, example API is:

http://example.com:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=col1&numShards=2&replicationFactor=1

I get the following error:

```
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter; [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/collections params={numShards=2&name=bisnis&replicationFactor=1&action=CREATE} status=500 QTime=2 
ERROR - 2014-01-08 15:36:07.736; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; null:java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:153)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleCreateAction(CollectionsHandler.java:281)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:112)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:608)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:215)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Are you running solr in Cloud mode? I was able to run your url and was successful to create, your URL is correct. What version of Solr are you on? Are you sure if this error is for this request? i see name=bisnis in your error log.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not running the the zookeeper instance implicitly or explicitly for your "SolrCloud".

To start the zookeeper instance implicitly add -DzkRun when you start your Solr node. Or explicitly -DzkHost=localhost:2181 (Obviously you should have a running zookeeper instance on port 2181 in your local)

Then run your query. It'll create the new collection.